# Starting tasks with a copy of a method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a downloader that will download two files simultaneously via WebRequest and Streams.

And for my understanding when I am starting new task they share the same method?

Which makes the download of two files impossible, Is there a way to make a new task or a thread to create a copy of a method?

What I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++) // 
{
    for (m_ThreadIndex = 0; m_ThreadIndex < 2; m_ThreadIndex++)
    {
        m_Downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
        m_Downloader.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
        var i1 = i;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => m_Downloader.Start(i1));
        i++;
    }
    Task.WaitAll();
}
```

Comment: Multiple tasks can run the same method. Each thread has it's own stack memory, so all local variables etc are not shared. A 'copy' of a method is not possible. You should pass the data for each task instead of an index. They should not use the same fields/property data. You should create multiple Downloader class instances.

Comment: Is the `m_Downloader` a `BackgroundWorkerThread`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It seems I'm to deep in this to understand half of what you said, The index is to indicate the row only, About the BackGroundWorkerThread if don't think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeroen van Lagen mentioned, it is not possible to make a copy of a method. You can instead create a new class and put the method in the class. Then you can create multiple class instances.

```
Class MyMainClass
{
    private void StartDownload()
    {
        var downloaderThread1 = new Downloader();
        var downloaderThread2 = new Downloader();
        var task1 = downloaderThread1.DownloadFileAsync(remoteAddress, downloadPath);
        var task2 = downloaderThread2.DownloadFileAsync(remoteAddress, downloadPath);
        Task.WaitAll();
    }

    class Downloader
    {           
        public async Task DownloadFileAsync(string remoteAddress, string downloadPath)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(remoteAddress, downloadPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this solution and then accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Dannz, you are welcome. Let me know if I can be any further help.

Comment: I'm having another difficulty when my task is not being awaited,  Could it be because my method lacks async? @Anthony

Comment: @Dannz There could be many reasons and lacking async keyword is one of them. Can you update your post if it is related to this topic? Otherwise, you'd better start a new post.

Comment: If I will make another post i will tag you, Thank you again :)